# RSA python encryption

Tags: python, encryption, rsa

(For School) I am trying to do  a simple RSA encryption that will encrypt string into blocks of three letters.
What can I change to get the math to work with a string rather than just integers?

```
import math

message = str(input("Enter Plaintext: "))

p = 521
q = 757
e = 11
n = p*q

def encrypt(me):
    en = math.pow(me, e)
    c = en % n
    print("Encrypted Message is: ", c)
    return c

print("Original Message is: ", message)
c = encrypt(message)
```

```
Enter Plaintext: zallaboardty
Original Message is:  zallaboardty
```

```
line 18, in <module>
    c = encrypt(message)
line 11, in encrypt
    en = math.pow(me, e)
TypeError: must be real number, not str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You are passing the string `"zallaboardty"` as `me` to the function then, in the first line of this function, calling `math.pow(me, e)`. What do you expect "zallaboardty" to the power of 11 to be? You can't do anything to get math to work with a string — you need to convert that string to some sort of number if you want to apply math to it.

Comment: First of all what you want to do? You clearly see the error you apply math's functions with string.

Comment: Don't use `math.pow`, instead use the [builtin pow function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) with three arguments. So `en = math.pow(me, e);  c = en % n` becomes instead `c = pow(me, e, n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The message size in textbook RSA is determined by the size of the modululs. So you have a modulus n that is 521 x 757. This allows log_2(521 x 757) / 3 = ~6.19 bits per character. So each character can only take up 6 bits, i.e. it is in the range [0..2^6) = [0..64) characters. ASCII is 7 bits per character, so that's a bit annoying as we cannot directly use it.

Let's make it easy and work in decimals. We can calculate n to be 521 x 757 = 394397. That means we can construct a number below n by concatenating three two digit numbers, as long as that is below 394397. This will always work if we use numbers of 39 or below. We can now create an alphabet of maximum 40 characters (as we can include zero).

Let's define an alphabet SPACE=0, A=1...Z=26 and DOT=27 for an alphabet of 28 characters that includes the ABC. Great, so now we only have to first convert a message to the index, say:
"HELLO WORLD." can be split into "HEL", "LO ", "WOR" and "LD.". So you take H="08", E="05" en L="12", so the number we get is "080512" or 080512. Great, you now have a number that can be handled by RSA. Beware that the numbers must be left-padded with zeros for this scheme to work.

Now decimals is using base 10. You can also use base 2^6 (remember the ~6.19 bits per character above) and create a number from binary instead. However, for starters, it is easier to mess around with decimals & strings.